# ORM bug in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I have something weird in displaying the list of symfony if use this code

```
 $products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findBy(["id" => array(3)]);
dump($products);
exit;
```

I manually add an id array(3). It display the list of my categories which is correct

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Product {#2939 ▼
    #id: 3
    #name: "test"
    #title: "Test"
    #categories: PersistentCollection {#2941 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: Product {#2939}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#355 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: null
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#2450 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#2942 ▼
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
    }
    #status: 1
    #scheduleAt: DateTime {#2936 ▶}
  }
]
```

but if I used this code

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
//product_id will generate value array
// result array(3)
$product_id = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findCategoryById($id);
$products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findBy(["id" => $product_id]);
```

the value of $product_id is array(3). This will only display one category which is wrong.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Product {#2939 ▼
    #id: 3
    #name: "test"
    #title: "Test"
    #categories : PersistentCollection {#2941 ▼
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#355 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: null
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#2450 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#2942 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
          0 => Category {#2684 ▶}
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
    #status: 1
    #scheduleAt: DateTime {#2936 ▶}
  }
]
```

Comment: Why are you setting array(3) as value? Shouldn't it be just '3'? $products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findBy(["id" => 3]);

Comment: I just do that because if I add more id.

Comment: We don't know what is `AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository::findCategoryById` doing…

Comment: in that repository. it only return the array(3) which is the same as what I add manually in my first code

Comment: It means when I call the findCategoryId(). it will return the value array(3).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find by Id (only one Id):

```
$product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find(3);// Here return only one object if exist in Db;
```

If you need want to use `where in` :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('m');
$qb->from('AppBundle:Product', 'm');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->in('m.id', array(1,2,3,4,12,10)));


$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); //Here return ArrayCollection
dump($result);
exit;
```

Or in DQL:

```
SELECT m FROM AppBundle:Product m WHERE m.id IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 10)
```

**And last shortly query:**

```
$products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findById([1,2,3,4,5,6, 12,10]);
dump($products);
exit;
```

Comment: I try this one. I always get the same result. It only displays one category.